# Tidy output from many single-variable models using purrr, broom

Tags: r, purrr, broom

I have a dataframe that comprises of a binary outcome column (`y`), and multiple independent predictor columns (`x1`, `x2`, `x3`...).

I would like to run many single-variable logistic regression models (e.g. `y ~ x1`, `y ~ x2`, `y ~ x3`), and extract the exponentiated coefficients (odds ratios), 95% confidence intervals and p-values for each model into rows of a dataframe/tibble. It seems to me that a solution should be possible using a combination of purrr and broom.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112046/using-purrrmap-to-iterate-linear-model-over-columns-in-data-frame) question is similar, but I can't work out the next steps of:

1. extracting only the values I need and
2. tidying into a dataframe/tibble.

Working from the example in the referenced question:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

df <- mtcars

df %>%
 names() %>%
 paste('am~',.) %>%
 map(~glm(as.formula(.x), data= df, family = "binomial"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After sleeping on it, the solution occurred to me. Requires the use of `map_df` to run each model, and `tidy` to extract the values from each model.

Hopefully this will be useful for others:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

df <- mtcars

output <- df %>%
  select(-am) %>%
  names() %>%
  paste('am~',.) %>%
  map_df(~tidy(glm(as.formula(.x), 
               data= df, 
               family = "binomial"), 
               conf.int=TRUE, 
               exponentiate=TRUE)) %>%
  filter(term !="(Intercept)")
```